# Live refreshing filenames list

Tags: tensorflow

What is the proper way of live updating the file list while keeping the tensorflow session is open?

I am aware of the word `once` in the `tf.train.match_filenames_once()` function name but could not find an alternative. Here is a snippet showing what I am trying to do:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

pattern = '/tmp/test_file_*'
filenames = tf.train.match_filenames_once(pattern)

# Create some files
for i in range(3):
    with open(f'/tmp/test_file_old_{i}', 'w'):
        pass

# Open session and initialize vars
init_op = tf.local_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init_op)

# Read filenames list before adding new files
filenames_result_1 = sess.run(filenames)
print('First filenames list:')
print(filenames_result_1)

# Create some new files
for i in range(3):
    with open(f'/tmp/test_file_new_{i}', 'w'):
        pass

# Read filenames list after adding new files
filenames_result_2 = sess.run(filenames)
print('Second filenames list:')
print(filenames_result_2)

# Trying to reinitialize the contents
sess.run(init_op)
filenames_result_3 = sess.run(filenames)
print('Third filenames list:')
print(filenames_result_3)
```

Output:

```py
First filenames list:
[b'/tmp/test_file_old_1' b'/tmp/test_file_old_0' b'/tmp/test_file_old_2']
Second filenames list:
[b'/tmp/test_file_old_1' b'/tmp/test_file_old_0' b'/tmp/test_file_old_2']
Third filenames list:
[b'/tmp/test_file_old_1' b'/tmp/test_file_old_0' b'/tmp/test_file_old_2']
```

I would have liked to obtain the up-to-date list of files instead.